# Qt 5 does not enter in lambda function?

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, begininvoke

When debug code, never enter into lambda function. Why do I have this problem?

```
QNetworkRequest req = QNetworkRequest(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = m_manager->get(req);

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished,[reply](){
        qDebug() << "start => ";
        if(reply ->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            QByteArray response = reply->readAll();
            qDebug() << "response => ";
            qDebug() << QString(response);
            return response;
        } else {
            QByteArray error = reply ->readAll();
            return error;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please, be more specific. Lambdas are a C++ feature. If the compiler accepts your code it will be considered in Qt 5 as well. (I very often use lambdas for signal slots in Qt 5 and never faced something different which wouldn't happen with a plain function as well.) What is your specific problem? Is it that a breakpoint in a lambda is not considered? Are the `qDebug()` messages emitted on console? I never had such an issue with VS 2013 or VS 2019 I can remember. What IDE / compiler / debugger are you using? There is still the possibility that your signal slot is just not called...

Comment: How are you deleting the `reply` object? It is not clear from yor code. If you happen to delete it before the lambda is executed, then the connection is automatically disconncted and hence the lambda is not executed.

Comment: Inside the `connect`-function you are missing the instance of the slot-member (probably `this`)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat QDebug() use like consle.log only for written data. For debugging use qt creator. I try not to use event loop to send requests for API. Because I created lambda function, but lambda sometimes return an empty response.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager delete reply object using    reply->deleteLater();. I fix problem but now my response sometimes is empty sometimes okay.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my problem, must create a signal for return data.

```
    QObject::connect(reply,&QNetworkReply::finished,this, [this, reply]() {
         qDebug() << "Got reply finished";
        if(reply ->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            m_json= reply->readAll();
            reply->deleteLater();
            emit workResponseChanged(m_workJson);
        } else {
            m_json= reply ->readAll();
            reply->deleteLater();
            emit workResponseChanged(m_workJson);
        }
    });
    return QByteArray();
```